# JBPM build with Maven

Tags: jbpm

Hello everybody please help. 
i wish to build jbpm from source in ubuntu 14.04 for that i have followed this steps

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm.git jbpm
 $ mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

but i have got this error :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce
>   (enforce-java-version) on project jbpm: Some Enforcer rules have
>   failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule
>   failed. -> [Help 1]

please help me

Answer (score 0):

What version of JDK do you use? jBPM 7.0 which is on `master` branch can only be compiled using Java 8. If you need to embed it in your application that uses older version, you can try jBPM 6.5 on `6.5.x` branch which is compatible with Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

As said in log

> Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.

There should be some additional info about error above. If not, please run mvn clean install -DskipTests -X

Since it says about enforce-java-version probably livthomas answer is correct and you should try compile JBPM with JDK 1.8